# MariaDB LOAD DATA INFO can't import single column file to single column table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to import the [10,000 common password list](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/) into a table to ban those passwords from being used in a given system.

The file is a single column TXT file. Trying to `LOAD DATA INFILE` that into a table with a single column gives me a primary key error. So, I thought, I'll set an id column with autoincrement, and then pass `null` for each row to trigger the keys to be indexed. That doesn't work either (or I have a syntax problem) because that gives me 10,000 rows with numbers and null password fields.

Can this be done, or should I just write a python script to add an index to each text line, and then import it that way?

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/passwords.txt' INTO TABLE `common_passwords` (password,id) SET id=@id+1,password=@password;
```

And here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `common_passwords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16384 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It seems like we should be able to do this rather easily in SQL...

Comment: Without the fields or `SET`, I get this error: `Duplicate entry '123456' for key 'PRIMARY'` (123456 is one of the passwords on the list). This is what started thsi problem to start with. In a perfect world, I'd get rid of the PRIMARY and indexes to get this imported, then go back and add an id column and re-index.

Comment: Not trying to be dense here, but I've read this over and over. What am I missing? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/load-data-infile/ I don't see anything about including it in a query except for using SELECT statements for `INTO OUTFILE` (Incidentally, I wrote a python script to add the ids and got it imported. But, this is still something I want to know / understand).

Answer (score 0):

To quote the manual:

> If you specify no FIELDS or LINES clause, the defaults are the same as if you had written this:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

and

> Interpret characters preceded by the escape character \ as escape sequences. For example, \t, \n, and \ signify tab, newline, and backslash, respectively. See the discussion of FIELDS ESCAPED BY later for the full list of escape sequences.

and

> If the FIELDS ESCAPED BY character is empty, escape-sequence interpretation does not occur.

and

> ... empty ('')

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

That is, if you have tabs or backslashes, the data will be mangled as it is read.  This may explain the problem you are having.

I *guess* this may be the fix:

```
FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''
```